# How to get elements and indices into original array with mask

Tags: python, numpy, intersection

I am trying to get both the elements and indices from two arrays where the elements match. I think I am overthinking this but I have tried the `where` function and intersection and cannot get it to work. My actual array is much longer but here two simple arrays to demonstrate what I want:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([0.00, 0.016, 0.033, 0.050, 0.067])
arr2 = np.array([0.016, 0.033, 0.050, 0.067, 0.083])

ind = np.intersect1d(np.where(arr1 >= 0.01), np.where(arr2 >= 0.01))
```

Printing `ind` shows `array([1, 2, 3, 4])`. Technically, I want the elements `1, 2, 3, 4` from `arr1` and elements `0, 1, 2, 3` from `arr2`, which gives the elements `0.016, 0.033, 0.050, 0.067`, which match in both arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` converts a boolean mask like `arr1 >= 0.01` into an index. You can select with the mask directly, but it won't be invertible. You need to invert the indices because you want to intersect from the original array, not the selection. Make sure to set `return_indices=True` to get indices from `intersect1d`:

```
index1 = np.nonzero(arr1 >= 0.01)
index2 = np.nonzero(arr2 >= 0.01)
selection1 = arr1[index1]
selection2 = arr2[index1]

elements, ind1, ind2 = np.intersect1d(selection1, selection2, return_indices=True)

index1 = index1[ind1]
index2 = index2[ind2]
```

While you get `elements` directly from the intersection, the indices `ind1` and `ind2` are referencing the masked selections. Since `index1` is the original index of each element in `selection1`, `index1[ind1]` converts `ind1` back into the `arr1` reference frame.

Your original expression was actually meaningless. You were intersecting the indices in each array that met your condition. That has nothing to do with the values at those indices (which wouldn't have to match at all). The seemingly correct result is purely a coincidence based on a fortuitous array construction.

Comment: What is the downvote for? I'd like to fix my answer if something is incorrect

Comment: Yes, this does the trick on this simplified arrays. Let me verify it works on the larger arrays before accepting this answer. Thanks for the quick reply on this problem.